# Change FusionChart map need to get rid of the orange background color from the color range slider bar

Tags: fusioncharts

I am working on the FushionChart map, the default orange background color does not work with the color scheme of my page. I have followed their examples to code the map, none of their example have this orange background and I wonder where is the orange bar coming from. 
PS: My map also had a black border that was supposed to be off by default, but mine was on even I copy the example word by word. I had to set showCanvasBorder to "0" to turn off the black border. I think this orange background color could be fixed by some config but I just don't know what chart attribute to change.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After asking my co-worker, that slider bar is actually called legend. I just set the color to white to blend in with the white background.

legendBgColor: "#FFFFFF",
legendBorderColor: "#FFFFFF"

Answer (score 0):

You have to use color ranges to define entity colors based on values,Since the process of defining colors for individual data buckets is not scalable, you need to group data values under defined data range buckets.
Using a gradient scale, you can specify colors associated with specific data points. This defines an automatic gradient scale across the data range. Entities appear in unique colors as per the data value position on the gradient scale.

```
    {
    "chart": {
        "caption": "Global Population Density",
        "theme": "fusion",
        "showLabels": "1",
        "formatNumberScale": "0"
    },
    "colorrange": {
        "minvalue": "0",
        "startlabel": "Low",
        "endlabel": "High",
        "code": "#FF4411",
        "gradient": "1",
        "color": [{
            "maxvalue": "25",
            "code": "#FFDD44",
            "displayValue": "Median"
        }, {
            "maxvalue": "100",
            "code": "#6baa01"
        }]
    },
    "data": [{
        "id": "NA",
        "value": "22.1",
        "showLabel": "1",
        "displayValue": "Moderate"
    },
    {
        "id": "SA",
        "value": "22.0",
        "showLabel": "1",
        "displayValue": "Moderate"
    },
    {
        "id": "AS",
        "value": "95.0",
        "showLabel": "1",
        "displayValue": "Dense"
    },
    {
        "id": "EU",
        "value": "72.5",
        "showLabel": "1",
        "displayValue": "Dense"
    },
    {
        "id": "AF",
        "value": "33.7",
        "showLabel": "1",
        "displayValue": "Moderate"
    },
    {
        "id": "AU",
        "value": "3.2",
        "showLabel": "1",
        "displayValue": "Sparse"
    }]
}
```

Sample Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/fusioncharts/r7L7xcv1/

To know more about this feature please refer - https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/map-guide/colouring-based-on-data-range#build-a-map-with-a-gradient-scale

https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-guide/chart-configurations/legend#customize-legend-appearance

Regarding Show Canvas Border, By default, the canvas border is not visible. To show the canvas border, set the showCanvasBorder attribute to 1.

https://fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-guide/chart-configurations/canvas#show-canvas-border